# Optimal threshold on classification probability

Tags: classification, threshold

I have a question regarding threshold on classification. In the problem listed below, are they stating that λ01 and λ10 are equal to zero? Listed below is the question.

Consider a case where we have learned a conditional probability distribution P (y|x). Suppose there are only two classes and let p0 = P (Y = 0|x) and p1 = P (Y = 1|x). Consider the loss matrix below:

predicted 
label ŷ  true label y
      0  1
0     0  λ01
1    λ10 0

Show that the decision ŷ that minimizes the expected loss is equivalent to setting a probability threshold θ and predicting ŷ = 0 if p1 < θ and ŷ = 1 if p1 ≥ θ. What is θ as a function of λ01 and λ10?

Comment: Could you reformat the question so the math displays properly? It's a little hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Also, please format your matrix as a matrix. Thank you!